# Number result not be changed when looping kotlin

Tags: for-loop, kotlin

i have a problem with my code

this is my code

```
        for (items in step) {
        var i = 1
        val tr = layoutInflater.inflate(
            R.layout.table_row,
            null
        ) as TableRow
        val no = TextView(this)
        no.text = i.toString()
        val step = TextView(this)
        step.text = items
        tr.addView(no)
        tr.addView(step)
        tvStep.addView(tr)

        //problem
        i++            
    }
```

the result in no column is just number 1, i want to step up number.
help me plase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `var i = 1` declaration outside (above) the loop.

Right now each time through the loop gets a separate variable called `i`, set to 1; it gets incremented at the end of the loop but immediately discarded.  Moving the declaration outside the loop will change that to use the same variable across all iterations, which will be incremented each time.